# How to use preg_match_all to obtain all images of a post

Tags: php, regex, image, extract, preg-match-all

I have an blog entry which has multiple images in it (sometimes one, sometimes two, sometimes three) and looks a bit like this:

```
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w133>
  <img class="yyy" title="title1" src="http://xxx/title1.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" />
</a>
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w134">
  <img class="yyy" title="title2" src="http://xxx/title2.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" />
</a>
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w135">
  <img class="yyy" title="title3" src="http://xxx/title3.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" />
</a>
```

with some text following this.

Now, I wonder how I can use preg_match_all to extract that first part. I now somewhat about PHP programming, but never used preg_match_all.

This code here does extract the last image only, which is not enough:

```
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post_content, $matches);
```

It would be great if someone could give me a hint how to achieve that, if it's possible at all. Thanks so much!

Comment: the . will match ANY characters so try [^<>] instead so it stays within the image tag

Comment: You'd probably be better off with an [HTML parser](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) instead of a regular expression. Then you could grab images with an XPath query.

Comment: @Waygood. Thx. Perhaps if I would use something like: ('/<a href.<img AND THAN SOMETHING HERE/></a>') it would extract the stuff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$post_content='<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w133>
  <img class="yyy" title="title1" src="http://xxx/title1.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" />
</a>
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w134">
  <img class="yyy" title="title2" src="http://xxx/title2.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" />
</a>
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w135">
  <img class="yyy" title="title3" src="http://xxx/title3.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" />
</a>
';

preg_match_all('/<a\s[^>]*href=([\"\']??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU', $post_content, $matches);
//print_r ($matches);//$matches - array which contains all your images
print $matches[0][0]; //first link with image
print $matches[0][1]; //second link with image
print $matches[0][2]; //third link with image
```

Output:

```
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w133&gt;
  &lt;img class=" yyy"="" title="title1" src="http://xxx/title1.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487">
</a>
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w134">
  <img class="yyy" title="title2" src="http://xxx/title2.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487">
</a>
<a href="http://xxx/" rel="attachment w135">
  <img class="yyy" title="title3" src="http://xxx/title3.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487">
</a>
```

Comment: That's the same than the above, the one I mentioned, no? It results in this:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img class="" title="title1" src="http://xxx/title1.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" /></a><a href="http://xxx" rel=""><img class="" title="title2" src="http://xxx/title2.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" /></a><a href="http://xxx" rel=""><img class="" title="title3" src="http://xxx/title3.jpg" alt="" width="650" height="487" /></a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://xxx/title2.jpg
        )

Comment: which is not exactly what I want, as it only takes the last image. And then, it doesn't get the <a> neither. Not sure if I need them however.

Comment: Great! Fabulous! Thanks so muchè

Comment: However, just checking again, and it seems that it doesn't include all photos/images. This one for example: `code`<a href="http://xxx/Paradiese.002.png" rel="shadowbox" title="Paradiese.002"><img src="http://xxx/Paradiese.002-1024x806.png" alt="" title="Paradiese.002" width="650" height="511" class="alignleft size-large wp-image-316" /></a>

Comment: Ah, oh, my fault. Had a tiny misspelling in the code. Works perfectly well! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"][^\/>]*>/Ui', $post_content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: This results only in: "Array ( [0] => Array ( ) [1] => Array ( ) )"